# How to display bitmap in ImgaeView with its actual width and height 

Tags: android, layout, bitmap, imageview, httpurlconnection

I download and image from the internet using the below two functions. What when display the download image in image view, its size(width and height( is different from the actual size. why ? as I have save the image to drawable folder and display it in the imageview it appears fine as its size.

java code :

```
public InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException{
    InputStream in = null;
    int respobse = -1;

    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    if(!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
        throw new IOException("It's not HTTP connection");
    try{
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect();

        respobse = httpConn.getResponseCode();

        enableHttpResponseCache();

        if(respobse == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            in= httpConn.getInputStream();
            Log.d("HTTP connection","OK");
        }
    }catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("HTTP ERROR",e.toString());
        throw new IOException();
    }
    return in;
}

public Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL){

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream in = null;

    try{
        in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        in.close();
    }catch(IOException ex){

    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

The layout containg the imageview is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/include21"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round" >



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgRecibeImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/round"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/img1" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtRecibeName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#80000000"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="Crispy Chicken and Sandwich"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="17sp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLoader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txtRecibeName"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtRecibeName"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you checked that the bitmap fits the density ? i mean , if you use a 100x100px image , it would be smaller on high density device and larger on a low density device ...

also , did you notice that you've set the size of the imageView to be fill-parent for one of its dimensions , and used fit-start ?

this makes the image stretch to what it can , under the rules you've set. if you set wrap-content for both dimensions , it would be more predictable.

Comment: >> the width is normal .. but the appears like it is compressed

Comment: please check if the input image has the same aspect ratio as the one being shown.